# Format Readonly file system

Tags: mount, read-only

I wanted to format my USB drive,

first, the folder is /dev/sr0 for whatever reason
second, Ubuntu 22.04 detects it as a cd/dvd
third, none of the known things such as `sudo umount /dev/sr0` then `sudo mkdosfs -F 32 -I /dev/sr0` doesn't work: `mkdosfs: unable to open /dev/sr0: Device or resource busy` even if I unmount it 1000000 times
ubuntu disks details say that it has `ISO 9660 (version Joliet Extension)` file in itself
which is an exe file called K3_Setup
I also tried: `sudo chmod 0755 * in the disk`
version: Ubuntu 22.04

***any new solution????***

Comment: You mention both 22 & 22.04 which are different products (22 being a *snap only flavor* of Ubuntu 22.04 Server) so which are you running?  There are differences between 22 & 22.04.   Are you running from that USB drive; you can't format it whilst it's *in-use* (where it'll appear as a CD as that is what the ISO emulates)

Comment: it is ubuntu 22.04
and i'm not running that in the folder I'm pretty sure that isn't In use
but I'll retry